# Show two button below each other in a Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following Shiny application

```
UI <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      splitLayout(cellWidths = c("80%", "20%"),
                  plotOutput("line_graph"),
                  selectInput("button1", "First", c(1, 5, 10),width = "50"),
                  selectInput("button2", "Button", c(1, 5, 10),width = "50%")
      )
    )
  )
)

Server <- function(input, output) {

  output$line_graph <- renderPlot({
    hist(100)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

Main main aim is that I get a plot on the left side (80%) and in the 20% right lane next to it I would like to have the two button under each other (with the same width).

The code above however does not give me the output I want. Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining your layout like this?

```r
UI <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("line_graph")
    ),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("button1", "First", c(1, 5, 10), width = "100"),
      selectInput("button2", "Button", c(1, 5, 10), width = "100")
    )
  )
)
```

**Another option** is to use `column` where in sum of its 1st parameter should come as 12. In this case it's 10+2 i.e. 10 for plot and 2 for dropdown.

```
UI <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(10,
           plotOutput("line_graph")),
    column(2,
           selectInput("button1", "First", c(1, 5, 10), width = "100"),
           selectInput("button2", "Button", c(1, 5, 10), width = "100"))
  )
))
```

Comment: Hi @Prem, thanks but that does not really answer my question. There should be a way so they appear next to each other in stead of on top of each other right?

Comment: _"I get a plot on the left side (80%) and in the 20% right lane next to it I would like to have the two button under each other (with the same width)"_ I think this is what you meant in your post. right? i.e. plot in left pane and both dropdown buttons in right pane on top of each other.

Comment: Jeah, but - for learning purposes - I want to understand how you can make two items appear under each other in when splitting up with cellwidths

Comment: See the updated answer. I hope it answers your query. Pls don't hesitate to reply back with followup question if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

That's the first time I use `splitLayout` and this seems weird. This works like this but there is a useless scrollbar that appears:

```
UI <- bootstrapPage(
  mainPanel(
    splitLayout(plotOutput("line_graph"),
                fluidRow(
                  column(width=2),
                  column(width=10,
                         selectInput("button1", "First", c(1, 5, 10), width="50px"),
                         selectInput("button2", "Button", c(1, 5, 10), width="50px")
                  )),
                cellWidths = c("60%", "40%")),
    width=12
  )
)

Server <- function(input, output) {
  output$line_graph <- renderPlot({
    hist(100)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```